Handling Stale Reads and Lost Updates in Galera Cluster During Large Transactions
I have a question about using Galera Cluster.
I understand that for large transactions (changing many rows), replication between nodes can take a long time. I also know that stale reads can occur in such scenarios.
Due to a stale read, a lost update happened. For example, 1 million rows were changed on Node A, and the transaction was certified between nodes, with only asynchronous replication left. When selecting on Node B, the changes from Node A cannot be read. If I select the changed rows on Node B and update them to different values, the update succeeds. This results in a lost update.
Questions:
I understand that Galera performs certification-based replication. In this case, does the update on Node B not cause a deadlock because the transaction on Node A has been certified and only the act of asynchronous replication is left?

If you experienced a lost uodate, then the answer is no, this situation does not cause a deadlock. But you reallyshould move this question to the DBA sisyer site of SO as it has nothing to do with programming
